# Validation callback in magento2

Tags: magento2, jquery, validation, form-validation

```
var dataForm = jQuery('#form');
dataForm.mage('validation');
function submitForm(){                
    if (dataForm.valid()){
        dataForm.submit();
    }
}
```

Everything is working well what i want some kind of `callback function` when `valid()` returns false.

I tried and found that there is some option for adding custom error messages like

```
dataForm.mage('validation',{
    errorPlacement:function(error,element){
        var errorPlacement = element;
        errorPlacement.after(error);
        /* we can do custom stuff here */
    }
});
```

But this doesn't works well it only create element for first time when validation called.

I need callback function that call everytime whenever validation failed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dataForm = jQuery('#form');
dataForm.mage('validation');
function submitForm(){                
    if (dataForm.valid()){
        dataForm.submit();
    }else{
        var elements = $('#submitbtn');
        $('.magerror').remove();
        var error = "<div class='magerror'>This is required field</div>";
        elements.after(error);
    }
}

<form class="forms" id="form">
    <div class="aaaa">
        <button type="submit" id="submitbtn">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you can try with above code

Comment: Thanks but this solution will not solve my problem. what i want is a callback for `valid()` method which triggers every time when the `valid()` returns false

Comment: you have to pass in else condition with function name and add else code in those functions

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to find the correct callback function but this workaround worked for me.

```
var dataForm = jQuery('#form');
dataForm.mage('validation');
function submitForm(){                
    if (dataForm.valid()){
        dataForm.submit();
    }
    else{
        jQuery('input.mage-error').each(function(){
            /* Do our custom stuff here */
        });
    }
}
```

What this does is whenever `valid()` returns `false` Magento adds `mage-error` class to each element.